# How to deploy to docker hub repository only for certain people?

Tags: docker

I am starting to learn docker. I got to the moment of deployment to the hub of my image. Can I somehow restrict access to this image? And as I understand it, in order to transfer the image to the client, you need to give the name of the image from the docker hub?

Answer (score 0):

for free accounts, you can have 1 private repository.

Check the official doc here: https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/

Comment: Tell me please, where are the images locally on the PC that need to be transferred, for example, to the customer? or should it always be through the hub?

Comment: you can have tarballs of the images to be shared with the customer, but most people either use private docker hub repos, or their own private registries. Also, most of the cloud providers offer their own private registries which you can also use.

Comment: in lincux or windows where can i find these tarballs ? I can't find

Comment: use the docker save command: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/.

not to be rude or anything, you are asking very basic questions without even looking them up :).